# Add a discount from the coupon if the price of the discounted product isn't more than 10%

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to do a discount from the coupon if the price of the discounted product isn't more than 10%. Now I have:

```
function action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $excluded_categories = array( 'czekolada-na-goraco', 'bita-smietana', 'czekoladziarki', 'czesci-zamienne', 'dystrybutory-do-napojow', 'gofrownice', 'kostkarki-luskarki', 'urzadzenia-cukiernicze', 'maszyny-do-lodow', 'maszyny-kawa-mrozona', 'miksery-lody-flurry' );
    // Initialize
    $coupon_flag = false;
    // Loop through applied coupons
    foreach ( $cart->get_applied_coupons() as $coupon_code ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Coupon Object
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
        // Only for certain types, several can be added, separated by a comma
        if ( in_array( $coupon->get_discount_type(), array( 'percent', 'percent_product' ) ) ) {
            $coupon_flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $coupon_flag ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Get product ID in
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            // NOT contains the definite term
            if ( ! has_term( $excluded_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                // Get regular price
                $regular_price = $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price();
                // Get promo price
                $promo_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
                $percentage = 10;
                $percent_price = $regular_price - ($regular_price * ($percentage / 100));
                // Set new price
                if ( $percent_price < $promo_price ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $regular_price );
                } else {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $promo_price ); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```

The above code applies a discount for the basic price if the promotional price is higher than the regular price -10%. However, if the promotional price is lower, it will charge the promotional price. If the promotional price is lower than the regular price -10%, it shouldn't be reduced by a percentage of the coupon. How can I get it?

EDIT - A little explanation:

**Product A:**
Regular price 200 euros,
Promotion price 100 euros,
Discount 50%.

**Product B:**
Regular price 200 euros,
Promotion price 190 euros,
Discount 5%.

I would like the discount to apply only to products whose promotional price doesn't exceed 10%. So the coupon should only work for product B as the current discount is less than 10%.

Comment: I find your question rather unclear (and I believe along with me, others too, since you have not yet received an answer to your question). 
Can you give an example based on some products. For example, product A normally costs 200 but is on promotion and now costs 100, of which 1 piece in cart and product B costs €50 (not in promotion), of which 2 pieces in cart. So the cart total is 200. If I apply a coupon of 10%, I want the price of product A change to… unless… possibly on the basis of a sreenshot to clearly indicate what should happen when.

Comment: Look at my edit